# Only owner should be able to edit or delete a List Item

Tags: list, permissions

*Scenario:*

1. User has 'Contribute' rights on a List.
2. User creates a new ListItem on this List.
3. User should only be able to edit or delete his own ListItems.

How can I define that only the Owner (Created By) should be able to edit or delete this ListItem ?

I was thinking about using an xslt if-statement with:

- ddwrt:IfHasRights(...)
- 'Created By' == 'Current User'

Is this correct ? Or are there easier ways to do this ?

See [this page](http://boris.gomiunik.net/2009/01/limit-parts-of-page-or-dataform-webpart-to-the-ones-with-rights/) for a complete overview from all Rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy.

[image]

Note : the only issue is that you are still able to click or delete option in the dropdownlist, but when you do this, you get an 'Access Denied' error from SharePoint.